# Dynamic hibernate connection

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jsf

We developing a JSF app connecting to existing PostgreSQL DB using Hibernate. Each of our clients have their own PostgreSQL data base. Is it possible to host only one app dynamically
connecting to  databases  based on client users login ( Each client have one PostgreSQL DB) .

for development we using only one client & a POJO access with hibernate.cfg.xml , we need to change this to take multiple clients.

```
  <property name='hibernate.connection.driver_class'>org.postgresql.Driver</property>
  <property   name='hibernate.connection.url'>jdbc:postgresql://testdev01/test_client</property>
  <property name='hibernate.connection.username'>username</property>
  <property name='hibernate.connection.password'>password</property>
  <property name='hibernate.connection.pool_size'>10</property>
  <property name='show_sql'>true</property>
  <property name='dialect'>org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
```

Comment: Add the properties in runtime when creating the SessionFactory, there is so many ways to achieve the whole concept, so try to be specific on what you're asking.

Comment: It is a Claim entry Application . When a company 'A' users logs in they should be connected to database  A_DB and B users logs in the should be connected to B_DB and so on.

Comment: For that to happend, there should be a common login database for both users, after they log in, any query should be done to the corresponding session factory, thats why you will add the properties at runtime and keep the factories in memory as singletons preferably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create SessionFactory fully programatically, see this: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html, for instance. So once the client is logged in you, can create separate SessionFactory for that client with its database.